# Python unflatten list based on second list

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I have 2 Python lists:

```
list_a = [[['Ab'], ['Qr', 'Zr']], [['Gt', 'Mh', 'Nt'], ['Dv', 'Cb']]]
list_b = [['Ab', 'QrB', 'Zr'], ['GtB', 'MhB', 'Nt6B', 'DvB', 'Cb6B5']]
```

I need to un-flatten `list_b` based on `list_a`. I need:

```
list_c = [['Ab'], ['QrB', 'Zr'], [['GtB', 'MhB', 'Nt6B'], ['DbB', 'Cb6B5']]]
```

Is there a way to get this `list_c`?

**Additional Information:**
The lists will always be defined such that:

- A partial string from `list_a` will always be found in `list_b`. eg. for `Gt` in one list, there will be either `Gt` or `GtB` in the 2nd list.
- Entries in each list cannot be in a different order - i.e. if `Qr` comes before `Zr` in one list then it (`Qr` or `QrB`) must come before `Zr` in the 2nd list.
- Each list can have a maximum of 20 strings in it.
- Each list has only unique strings.. eg. `Gt` cannot occur 2 or more times in any list.

**Attempt:**

Here is what I have tried:

```
list_c = [[],[]]
        for ty,iten in enumerate(list_b):
            for q in iten:
                for l_e in list_a:
                    for items in l_e:
                        for t,qr in enumerate(items):
                            if qr in q:
                                list_c[ty].append([q])
```

the output of this is:

```
[[['Ab'], ['QrB'], ['Zr']], [['GtB'], ['MhB'], ['Nt6B'], ['DbB'], ['Cb6B5']]]
```

The problem is that `['QrB'], ['Zr']` should be combined `['QrB','Zr']` just like they are combined in `list_a`.

**Attempt 2:**

```
for ty,iten in enumerate(list_b):
    for q in iten:
        for l_e,m in enumerate(list_a):
            for ss,items in enumerate(m):
                for t,qr in enumerate(items):
                    if qr in q:
                        list_a[l_e][ss][t] = q
```

This works and produces the required output:

```
[[['Ab'], ['QrB', 'Zr']], [['GtB', 'MhB', 'Nt6B'], ['DvB', 'Cb6B5']]]
```

However, it (attempt 2) is too long and I would like to know: it does not seem that this is the proper way to do this in Python. Is there is a more Pythonic way to do this?

Comment: Can you please state 1. The logic 2. Whatever you have tried ?

Comment: Are you sure your example data is correct? No idea how you can get `['Mg0', 'Cb605']` from `[..., 'DvB', 'Cb6B5']`

Comment: @achampion, thanks. Fixed the question.

Comment: I think it is changing of values then unflatening

Comment: I have updated the original post with my attempt and the resulting output. It is missing something as I explained.

Comment: for, for, for, for for, is never the way to do anything…

Comment: @septi: Yes, I know, that is my main problem with the approach I have used.

Comment: What if a partial string from `list_a` is not found in `list_b`? And vice versa? Can they be in a different order in the 2 lists? Are the lists short like your examples or can they potentially be very long? Is there a fixed set of codes from which the strings in `list_a` and `list_b` are drawn? Are the values all unique? ... and so on. If you could give a few more examples or some context you may get better solutions.

Comment: @Stuart: Thanks, these are important questions. I have added this information to the OP.

Answer (score 2):

If all you care about is the length of the sublists in `list_a` then can transform `list_a` into its sublist lengths and then use that to slice the sublists of `list_b`:

```
# Transform list_a into len of sublists, (generator of generators :)
index_a = ((len(l2) for l2 in l1) for l1 in list_a))  
list_c = []
for flatb, index in zip(list_b, index_a):
    splitb = []
    s = 0
    for i in index:
        splitb.append(flatb[s:s+i])
        s += i
    list_c.append(splitb)
```

Value of `list_c`:

```
[[['Ab'], ['QrB', 'Zr']], [['GtB', 'MhB', 'Nt6B'], ['DvB', 'Cb6B5']]]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a recursive variant for arbitrary depth of nesting. Not too pretty, but should work.

```
list_a = [[['Ab'], ['Qr', 'Zr']], [['Gt', 'Mh', 'Nt'], ['Dv', 'Cb']]] 
list_b = [['Ab', 'QrB', 'Zr'], ['GtB', 'MhB', 'Nt6B', 'DvB', 'Cb6B5']]

def flatten(l):
    for el in l:
        if isinstance(el, list):
            for sub in flatten(el):
                yield sub
        else:
            yield el

def flitten(l1, l2, i):
    result = []
    for j in l1:
        if isinstance(j, list):
            i, res = flitten(j, l2, i)
            result.append(res)
        else:
            result.append(l2[i])
            i += 1
    return i, result

def flutten(l1, l2):
    i, result = flitten(l1, list(flatten(l2)), 0)
    return result

print(flutten(list_a, list_b))
# prints [[['Ab'], ['QrB', 'Zr']], [['GtB', 'MhB', 'Nt6B'], ['DvB', 'Cb6B5']]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not look too long given the fairly complicated nature of the task (find a list within a list within a list and match it to a list within another list according to the first two letters, and replace the original value with the matched value retaining the nested structure of the original list...)

You could at least eliminate one of the loops like this:

```
for sub_a, sub_b in zip(list_a, list_b):
    for inner_a in sub_a:
        for i, a in enumerate(inner_a):
            for b in sub_b:
                if b.startswith(a):
                    inner_a[i] = b
```

If you want a more general solution it will probably involve recursion as in @Tibor's answer.

EDIT: Given the extra information you have supplied, you could recursively work through `list_a`, replacing all the short strings with their full versions from an iterator based on the flattened version of `list_b`. This uses the fact that the strings appear in the same order in both lists with no duplicates.

```
def replace_abbreviations(L, full_names):
    for i, item in enumerate(L):
        if isinstance(item, basestring):
            L[i] = full_names.next()
        elif isinstance(item, list):
            replace_abbreviations(item, full_names)

replace_abbreviations(list_a, (item for L in list_b for item in L))
```

Alternatively you can get a flattened list of the indices of each string in both lists and then loop through those:

```
def flat_indices(L):
    for i, item in enumerate(L):
        if isinstance(item, list):
            for j, inner_list in flat_indices(item):
                yield (j, inner_list) 
        else:
            yield (i, L)

for (a, i), (b, j) in zip(flat_indices(list_a), flat_indices(list_b)):
    a[i] = b[j]
```

Comment: It doesn't look like the OP cares that the items actually match in anyway (e.g. `startswith`), only that it is similarly partitioned (e.g. `len` of sublists in `list_a`).

Comment: @achampion - maybe. The problem needs to be specified a bit more clearly to provide the best response. Your solution assumes the items are already in the right order.

Comment: Agreed! I am assuming based on the OPs attempts not the stated problem.

Comment: It is a combination of what you both said: I am checking if a partial string from `list_a` is found in a full string from `list_b` - if so, then I require a similar partitioning. The partial string occurs at the beginning so `startswith()` should work. However, my main problem is the numerous `for` statements, as per septi's comment in the OP.